# Not able to use UI-Router in AngularJS 1.x with query params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using UI-Router with AngularJS 1.5.9 and I try to handle the route '/reregister' with a query parameter in it.

I try to invoke this URL form outside (by a link):

```
https://myapp.herokuapp.com/#/register-slack&reregister=T2KLC5H3Q
```

But everytime the URL is redirected to

https://myapp.herokuapp.com/#!/

I also wonder why there is a ! sign added  after the # sign in the url.

I have the following $stateProviderConfig for this purpose:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $stateProvider
        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
            })
            .state('register-slack', {
                url: '/register-slack',
                templateUrl: 'views/register-slack.html',
                controller: 'registerSlackCtrl'
            })
            .state('reregister-slack', {
                url: '/reregister-slack?id',
                params: {
                    id: { value : ""},
                },
                templateUrl: 'views/register-slack.html',
                controller: 'registerSlackCtrl'
        })
            .state('confirm-registration', {
                url: '/confirmation',
                templateUrl: 'views/show-confirmation.html'
            })
            .state('show-skills', {
                url: '/about-skills',
                templateUrl: 'views/show-skills.html'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the URL should be fixed from

> https://myapp.herokuapp.com/#/register-slack&reregister=T2KLC5H3Q

to

> https://myapp.herokuapp.com/#/register-slack?reregister=T2KLC5H3Q

notice the `&` and `?`. In a URL the first paremeter should always beging with `?` and subsequent params with `&` as in `/contacts?myParam1=value1&myParam2=wowcool`

Second you are using `rereigster` which if you want to capture as a value gracefully you might want to handle separately with the following state definition:

```
.state('reregister-slack', {
                url: '/reregister-slack?rereigster',
                params: {
                    id: { value : ""},
                },
                templateUrl: 'views/register-slack.html',
                controller: 'registerSlackCtrl'
        })
```

OR

You may want to change the URL to

> https://myapp.herokuapp.com/#/register-slack?id=T2KLC5H3Q

because you already have a route for `?id`.

UPDATE: Additional information on handling #! format hash prefixes.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
```

Comment: Thank you! Why do I have a #! instead of # as the routing sign? I never had such before.

Comment: When there is no match it will go to otherwise `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')` Seeing `&` where not expected  got it confused.

Comment: I use the link https://guruservice.herokuapp.com/#!/reregister-slack?id=T2KLC5H3Q and the state in app.js is now: .state('reregister-slack', {
            url: '/reregister-slack?id',
            templateUrl: 'views/reregister-slack.html',
            controller: 'registerSlackCtrl'
        })
I could not get rid of this strange #! sign because it is still showing up.

Comment: Can you remove the strange `!` character in  guruservice.herokuapp.com/#!/reregister-slack?id=T2KLC5H3Q

Comment: Also you can configure $locationProvider and set locationProvider.hashPrefix

Comment: When I remove the ! character the route does not get processed. And I did not set the hashPrefix to ! manually. I wonder why it showed up at all.